# Comparing DataRow with other DataRows

Tags: c#

I have a generic `List` of `MatchingResult` type *(see `MatchingResult` type implementation below)*.

I was able to use for loop to get the result I want, but I'd also like to know using lambda expression or LINQ, how to extract all data rows (from `Matches` property) that match with the `Left` property?

The `MatchingResult` class:

```
public class MatchingResult
{
    public DataRow Left { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my List of `MatchingResult`:

```
List<MatchingResult> list = PopulateList();
```

The end output would be a list of `DataRows` that satisfied the aforementioned condition.

Edit: `DataRows` have the same number of columns/name  and in the same order.

Sample data:

DataRow (Left)

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
--------+---------+--------
A       |   X     |  Y
```

DataRows (Matches)

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
--------+---------+--------
A       |   X     |  Y
A       |   O     |  W
A       |   X     |  Y
```

In the above example, the expected result is List of DataRows that contain below data:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
--------+---------+--------
A       |   X     |  Y
A       |   X     |  Y
```

Comment: What are you going to match on specifically in order to include the `DataRow`s you'd want to keep.

Comment: The DataRow from the Left property, comparing it to the list of DataRow in the Matches property. DataRows contain the same columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So you just want to compare columns names in `Matches` property to `Left` property (column names, if they match then include that `DataRow` right?

Comment: that's right @zaggler

Comment: @PeterCsala - I was able to solve it using for loop. I just wanted to know what are the other  alternative ways to achieve the same output

Comment: @yonan2236 I think if you could share that code as well then that would give clarity about what do you really want to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide some mock data as well please?

Comment: @zaggler - ok, give me some time

Comment: @zaggler - kindly see my edits above for the sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the existing [`DataRowComparer.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcomparer.default?view=net-5.0) which compares all fields:

```
List<MatchingResult> matches = list
    .Select(m => new MatchingResult 
    {
        Left = m.Left,
        Matches = m.Matches.Where(r => DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(m.Left, r)).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer. Notice that he asked for a simpler result - a list of data rows `List<DataRow> Matches = list.Select(m => m.Matches.Where(r => DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(m.Left, r))).ToList()`

Comment: @ShayD: Ah ok, i overlooked that, thanks. But you need to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` then.

Comment: Ok. You actually helped me now to assimilate `SelectMany` function. My expression whould return `List<List<DataRow>>`? and `SelectMany` merge those lists to one list. whould it?

Comment: @ShayD: Yes, SelectMany extracts items from sequences/collection, so "flattens" them and put them all into one sequence. Merge would suggest that duplicates are removed which isn't the case(you need `Distinct` then).